# How to join arbitrary parts of url in Python?

Tags: python, url

`urljoin` corrupts the data

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
base = "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1"
tail = "/employees"
urljoin(base, tail)
```

returns

```
'https://dummy.restapiexample.com/employees'
```

eating "/api/v1".

Comment: That's not corrupted, that's correct according to the documentation.

Comment: @PeterWood np, so, whats the function that works normally?

Comment: `tail = "employees"`

Comment: Perhaps `str.join`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 This won't drop leading/trailing slashes as needed.

Comment: @PeterWood this fixes data, not function

Answer (score -1):

`base` and `tail` are strings. `''.join([base, tail])` is one such way to join these strings:

```
>>> base = "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1"
>>> tail = "/employees"
>>> ''.join([base, tail])
'https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'
```

Strings have a `join` method, which takes in a list of strings and returns a concatenated string from said list, with copies of the calling string separating the substrings which are copies of the strings in the list -- so, for example, `'/'.join(['a','s','d','f'])` returns `'a/s/d/f'`. If `''` calls this method, it simply returns the list concatenated into one string.